# Magento 2 - Content deploy creating folders instead of file

Tags: magento2, linux

[image]

Magento 2 - Content deploy creating folders instead of file

Answer (score 0):

I think you developer mode is on.

Magento create symlink in developer or default mode.

To make it correct you need to change mode to production

php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production

you can use above command to change mode

Comment: I have already tried that.

Comment: ok i am not sure this is a solution or valid way but try this

Open your di.xml (app/etc/di.xml) and check around line 580 you should find something like this  Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink and change it to Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy

Answer (score 0):

As I debugged, that is server issue, so now before running content deploy you should remove or rename the pub/static folder.

Thanks